# How to test if method from one class, calls method from the other class using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

```
     public interface Interface1
     {
        void DoSomething1(int a);
     }

     public interface Interface2
     {
        void DoSomething2(int a);
     }

    public class Class1: Interface1
    {
        private Interface2 _interface2;

        public Class1(Interface2 _interface2)
        {
            this._inteface2= _interface2;
        }

        public void DoSomething1(int a)
        {
            _interface2.DoSomething2(a);
        }
    }

public class Class2: Interface2
    {
        public void DoSomething2(int a)
        {
            // some action
        }
    }
```

This is code that is simplifed.
I wonder how to test if Class1 calls DoSomething2(int a) from Class2 using Moq, on specific TestCases in C#?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and where you are having difficulties in a [mcve]. That way it shows that some effort was involved in trying to figure it out instead of just a show me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you going to test Class1 you should mock it's dependencies, in this case Interface2 like this

```
//First create the mock
var mocked = new Mock<Interface2>();

//then setup how the mocked interface methods should work
mocked.Setup(a=>a.DoSomething2(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(null);

//Add the mocked object to the Class1 constructor
var class1 = new Class1(mocked.Object);

//then Act on your class1 which will use your mocked interface
class1.DoSomething1(1);
```

Comment: Thank you, problem was in Setup. I haven't used "It.IsAny<int>"

Comment: @hurms Why did you mark my answer as correct and then remove it? didn't I provide the correct solution?

Comment: I don't know. I just cliked correct for the other answer too, and then it unchecked your's I assume. My bad.

Comment: @hurms yes, only one correct answer per question. You can upvote as many answers as u like only

Answer (score 0):

As you are injecting `Interface2` to `Class1` constructor, so you need to mock it using Moq. Then you need to execute DoSomething1 and call `Verify` method to make sure that the method of `Interface2` was called once. If it wasn't - the test will fail. Example is below:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void DoSomething1_DoSomething2IsCalled()
    {
        //Setup
        //create a mock for Class1 dependency 
        var mock = new Mock<Interface2>();
        var sut = new Class1(mock.Object);

        //execute
        sut.DoSomething1(It.IsAny<int>());

        //test
        mock.Verify(m => m.DoSomething2(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Sam Onela. Thought comments should be enough. Will put an update

Comment: I'm using Verify method, now I have another question. 
If I want to test it with bad parameter so the second method is never called how shoud I implement first method?
I have implementd method so it throws exception if parameter is wrong so when I run unit test, it always throws an exception. It never gives me green light that second method is not called one time.

Used mocked.Verify(a => a.DoSomething2(a), Times.Never());

Thank you  for your answer.

Comment: if throwing an exception is your expectation I'd recommend to use the following: Assert.Throws<TypeOfExpectedException>(() => { _sut.DoSomething(); })